# Is this in row echelon form?

Tags: matrices

We are supposed to get the following matrix in Row Echelon Form

Original

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -4 & 7\\
-3 & -6 & 10\\
 1 & 2  & -3\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

I got

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -4 & 7\\
0 & -6 & 10\\
 0 & 0  & 0.5\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -4 & 7\\
-3 & -6 & 10\\
 1 & 2  & -3\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
after $\frac{-3}{2}R_1+R_2\to R_2$ and $\frac{1}{2}R_1+R_3\to R_3$
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -4 & 7\\
0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{2}\\
 0 & 0  & 0.5\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
then $R_2+R_3\to R_3$
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -4 & 7\\
0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{2}\\
 0 & 0  & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
**Note that** determinant of given matrix is zero but the one you have calculate has nonzero determinant so you have to be sure it isnot correct.